# SwiftUI: strange behavior with onAppear

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a IOS app with SwiftUI that uses `NavigationView`and hides the Navigation Bar on the first view (and only on the first one).

So I created an ObservableObject

```swift
class NavBarShowViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isHidden: Bool = true
}
```

and in my Content View

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var navBarShowViewModel = NavBarShowViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Home()
                .navigationBarHidden(self.navBarShowViewModel.isHidden)
        }
        .environmentObject(self.navBarShowViewModel)
    }
}
```

Now in Home I have:

```swift
struct Home: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navBarShowViewModel: NavBarShowViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: FirstPage()) {
                    Text("Go!")
                }
                
                Text("Hello World")

                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Home")
        }
        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.navBarShowViewModel.isHidden = true
        })
    }
}
```

Now `FirstPage()` has the exact structure of `Home()`, except that has a different title

```swift
 .navigationBarTitle("First Page")
```

and onAppear has the following code:

```swift
.onAppear(perform: {
    self.navBarShowViewModel.isHidden = false
})
```

With this setup, the app works.

But if inside `FirstPage()` I navigate further, for example going to `SecondPage()` (which is for sake of simplicity, identical to `FirstPage()` with a different title) and then hitting back until I return to Home, `onAppear` here on `Home()` is not called, so it shows the navigation bar title.

Could someone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is about how SwiftUI engine tracks views and if it really *appears*... anyway, what it is can be determined as it is how *child* views appear/disappear on navigation stack, so possible solution is to add `onDisappear` in `FirstPage`, like

```
struct FirstPage: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var navBarShowViewModel: NavBarShowViewModel

    var body: some View {

        ... other code here

        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.navBarShowViewModel.isHidden = false
        })
        .onDisappear(perform: {
            self.navBarShowViewModel.isHidden = true
        })
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4